# Android rotation does not work in ObjectAnimator

Tags: android, android-animation, objectanimator

I use an Animator XML to animate an ImageView. The ImageView should grow (from 0f to 1f, Y faster than X) and rotate 90° from 90 to 0.
I use this XML file for the animation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:ordering="together">
    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="500"
        android:propertyName="scaleY"
        android:valueFrom="0f"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
        android:valueTo="1f"
        android:valueType="floatType" />

    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="1000"
        android:propertyName="scaleX"
        android:valueFrom="0f"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
        android:valueTo="1f"
        android:valueType="floatType" />

    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="1000"
        android:transformPivotX="0dp"
        android:transformPivotY="0dp"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:propertyName="rotate"
        android:valueFrom="90"
        android:valueType="floatType"
        android:valueTo="0" />

</set>
```

When I apply the Animator with

```
AnimatorSet set = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(this,
                R.animator.login_bubble_animation);
        set.setTarget(mContactBubble);
        set.start();
```

everything except the rotation works, so the ImageView grows but does not rotate. I already used

```
RotateAnimation rotate = new RotateAnimation(90, 0, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
            0.5f,  Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    rotate.setDuration(1000);
    mContactBubble.startAnimation(rotate);
```

which does work but it would an advantage if it is inside the XML file.

Comment: android:propertyName="rotationX" or rotationY

Comment: @mt0s this does work but I want a rotation around the z axis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your property string name `rotate` is not valid. You need to use `rotation`, or else `rotationX` and/or `rotationY`, just like you did for scale. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html#views for a list of properties that work with `ObjectAnimator`

Comment: Worked, thank you. Funny to see that even after 5 years of coding so small mistakes make you despair.

Answer (score 3):

You're using an incorrectly named property: `rotate`. It should be `rotation`.

The view class must have setters and getters for that attribute for it to be available as a property.